# Angular 5 HttpClient GET-Request isn't closed

Tags: angular, typescript, http, http-get, subscribe

I am using a Http-GET request to receive some json from my backend.

Service:

```
public categories: BehaviorSubject<Category[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);           

constructor() {
   const sub = this.http.get<ResponseInterface>(environment.apiUrl +  'categories')
     .subscribe(response => {
        categories.next(response.data)
     }, (error: any) => {
        sub
     }, () => { 
        sub.unsubscribe();
   });
}
```

Component:

```
this.service.categories.subscribe(categories => {
      if (categories !== null) {
        this.categories = categories;
      }
    });
```

Everything works fine in development (ng serve --aot)

If I am using the request in production it slows down my browser, so I have to end the script manually in order to use my browser again. But surprisingly the answer of the request appears in the network tab, as soon as I stop the script.

[image: Network log]

But the most annoying thing is that this error only appears 9/10 times. Has anyone seen something similar?

Comment: Yes, I have experimented some problems between dev version and prod version with ng cli, what angular version are you using?

Comment: try to change the way you are doing that. In the service, create a function that only returns the observable: return this.http.get<ResponseInterface>(environment.apiUrl +  'categories'); And in the component call the service function and append the .subscribe. Don't use the constructor in the service, create a function

Comment: @Kalamarico I'm using Angular 5.2.0. I was expecting, that I have to change it to a non-constructor solution. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix the problem by, assigning an empty array ([]) to the BehaviorSubject instead of null.

```
public categories: BehaviorSubject<Category[]> = new BehaviorSubject([])
```